# Почему ошибка "InvalidArgumentException Trailing data" если использую toArray() для выборки из БД?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

Использую Eloquent при обращении к БД. Метод в модели:

```
    public static function lastreport(){
        $lastReport = DayReport::with('elementary')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->where("username", "=", Auth::user()->name)
            ->first();
        return $lastReport;
    }
```

Обращаюсь к нему из контроллера:

```
dd(DayReport::lastReport()->toArray());
```

Хочу вытащить резутаты и отправить их в виде массива или json клиенту, там js это дело распарсит и отобразит на странице. Но когда добавляю **toArray()**, то получаю ошибку **"InvalidArgumentException Trailing data"**. Если нет **toArray()**, то во вложенной структуре вижу интересующие меня данные связанных таблиц. Как устранить ошибку или как лучше отправить джаваскрипту данные иным способом?

Answer (score 0):

Model DayReport

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DayReport extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
    protected $table = {{table-name}};
}
```

Controller DayReport

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\DayReport;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    class ShopsController extends Controller
    {
    public function lastreport(Request $request)
    {
     $lastReport = DayReport::orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->where("username",Auth::user()->name)
            ->first();
    print_r($lastReport);die;
        return $lastReport;

      }
    }
```